# How to resolve a java.lang.Exception in Oracle Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle, exception, oracle-enterprise-manager

After creating a db using Database Configuration Assistant, I go to Enterprise Manager, log into it, and it tells me, that `java.lang.Exception: Exception in sending Request :: null`. OracleDBConsole for this db, and iSQLPlus services are started. When I run `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\emctl status dbconsole`, it says

> EM Daemon is not running.

How do I deal with this? How do I start the EM daemon?

Comment: did you start the listener for the database before the emctl command?

Comment: I don't think so. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\emctl start dbconsole
```

Comment: It says, "...The requested service has already been started". And emctl status still says, that "EM Daemon is not running".

Comment: Well, it actually worked. I restarted the dbconsole. At first it said, that EM daemon is still not running, but in about 15 minutes it was okay. Thank you.